# How does authentication work if the password provides a different salt on every login?

Tags: passwords, hash, salt

How does an application authenticate a users password if every time he provides his password to access his account the password provides a different salt?

Comment: How would the password provide a different salt?

Answer (score 7):

The premise of your question is incorrect. A different salt is not used every time the password is provided.

This is how password based quthentication works:

- Upon registration, the user sends her password to the server. The server generates a random salt, and stores the salted hash *and* the salt.
- Upon login, the user again sends her password to the server. The server retrieves the stored salt for that user, rehashes the password with it, and compares it to the stored hash.

Answer (score 2):

It might get clearer if you separate the registration process from authentication process.

**At registration time:**

- User provides credentials. Most often this includes UserID + Password. **Note that the user (or the user agent) does not provide any salt at this stage.**
- Server generates a unique salt for that user and uses it in a one-way hashing algorithm to generate a password-digest.
- The salt is stored in the database along with the password-digest.

**At authentication time (when user comes back to login) - each time:**

- User provides the UserID + Password. **Note that the user doesn't supply any salt.**
- Server uses the UserID as the search key and retrieves the salt and
  the stored-password-digest for that user
- Server then combines the user-supplied Password + retrieved salt the same way as before - to generate a the user-supplied-password-based-digest. **Note that the salt is retrieved from database, not freshly generated.**
- Server then compares the stored-password-digest with the user-supplied-password-based-digest to decide whether authentication is success or fail.